# Possible to change Notepad++ UI font size without changing OS settings?

Tags: windows, notepad++, fonts

The menu font is too small, as well as the dialogue box text. It is very difficult to read the text such as on the Preferences dialogue box. Is there any way to make them bigger other than:

- Increase the system DPI: It is already 200%, and useless stuff like the window title bar are unnecessarily thick and big. I cannot afford them to make them even bigger; I have little vertical screen space left.
- Without changing the system font size using registry: For some stupid reason, the height of window title bar seems to be twice as the system font size. So, increasing the system font makes the title bar stupidly big as well as other things like the toolbar buttons on the ribbon menu of File Explorer.

I am asking about increasing the UI font size (menu, dialogue box, etc), not the editor font size.

Answer (score 1):

In Settings, in the Search box, type in Make Text Bigger and use the Text slider to increase the items you list above. I use 150% Scale (versus 200%) and then 110% Text size. Try also 115% or 120% .

Windows 10 V1809 or higher.

The adjustment above affects Windows, Office and a number of my own apps (but not all). I expect this to change over time with new Windows Updates.

In the meantime, people would need to check their particular app with the App Support Site.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it increased the menu text size and some other text sizes like the file names in File Explorer. However, it did not increase the dialogue text size of Notepad++. But if there is no side effect (like some unwanted things get bigger), which I need more time to see, it is better than nothing.

Comment: Where there is no effect (you point out Notepad++) that is a function of the application itself and there is no Windows fix for that. You would have to go to the application support site to see if the application has a fix. The change above affects a number of my apps. I expect more as time goes by (Windows Feature Updates)